# Switch from dyadic to monadic interpretation in a J sentence

Tags: refactoring, j

I am trying to understand composition in J, after struggling to mix and match different phases. I would like help switching between monadic and dyadic phrases in the same sentence.

I just made a simple dice roller in J, which will serve as an example:

```
   d=.1+[:?[#]
   4 d 6
2 3 1 1
   8 d 12
10 2 11 11 5 11 1 10
```

This is a chain: "d is one plus the (capped) roll of x occurrences of y"

But what if I wanted to use >: to increment (and skip the cap [: ), such that it "switched" to monadic interpretation after the first fork?
It would read: "d is the incremented roll of x occurrences of y".

Something like this doesn't work, even though it looks to me to have about the right structure:

```
   d=.>:&?[#]
   d
>:&? ([ # ])
```

(If this approach is against the grain for J and I should stick to capped forks, that is also useful information.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at a dyadic fork `a(c d f h g)b` where c,d,f, g and h are verbs and a and b are arguments, which is evaluated as: `(a c b) d (a f b) h (a g b)` The arguments are applied dyadically to the verbs in the odd positions (or tines c,f and g) - and those results are fed dyadically right to left into the even tines d and h. Also a fork can be either in the form of (v v v) or (n v v) where v stands for verbs and n stands for nouns. In the case of (n v v) you just get the value of n as the left argument to the middle tine.

If you look at your original definition of `d=.1+[:?[#]` you might notice it simplifies to a dyadic fork with five tines `(1 + [: ? #)` where the `[ # ]` can be replaced by `#` as it is a dyadic fork (see definition above).

The `[:` (Cap) verb returns no value to the left argument of `?` which means that `?` acts monadically on the result of `a # b` and this becomes the right argument to `+` which has a left argument of `1`.

So, on to the question of how to get rid of the `[:` and use `>:` instead of `1 + ...`

You can also write `([: f g)` as `f@:g` to get rid of the Cap, which means that `([: ? #)` becomes `?@:#` and now since you want to feed this result into `>:` you can do that by either:

```
   d1=.>:@:?@:# 
   d2=. [: >: ?@:#
   4 d1 6
6 6 1 5
   4 d2 6
2 3 4 5
   8 d1 12
7 6 6 4 6 9 8 7
   8 d2 12
2 10 10 9 8 12 4 3
```

Hope this helps, it is a good fundamental question about how forks are evaluated. It would be your preference of whether you use the `([: f g)` or `f@:g` forms of composition.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I completely misunderstood fork evaluation but lucked into the right answer because 1 and [: ignored the arguments given to them. :-)

Comment: I can't comment on your understanding of fork, but you are correct that [: and any noun (in your example 1) ignores the arguments in the (n v v) fork

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the main simple patterns of verb mixing in J:

```
          (f @: g) y    =    f (g y)             NB. (1) monadic "at"
        x (f @: g) y    =    f (x g y)           NB. (2) dyadic "at"
        x (f &: g) y    =    (g x) f (g y)       NB. (3) "appose"
          (f g h)  y    =    (f y) g (h y)       NB. (4) monadic fork 
        x (f g h)  y    =  (x f y) g (x h y)     NB. (5) dyadic  fork
            (f g)  y    =       y  f (g y)       NB. (6) monadic hook 
          x (f g)  y    =       x  f (g y)       NB. (7) dyadic  hook
```

A nice review of those is [here (compositions)](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/learning/08.htm) and [here (trains)](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/learning/09.htm).

Usually there are many possible forms for a verb. To complicate matters more, you can mix many primitives in different ways to achieve to same result.

Experience, style, [performance](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/special.htm) and other such factors influence the way you'll combine the above to form your verb.

In this particular case, I would use @bob's `d1` because I find it clearer to read: `increase the roll of x copies of y`:

```
>: @ ? @ $
```

For the same reason, I am replacing `#` with `$`. When I see `#` in this context, I automatically read "number of elements of", but maybe that's just me.

Comment: I automatically read "angry face" when I see >: @ but otherwise I think my brain can handle the composition more easily.